# The below expression I used in informatica. But the expression is not working for me. it shows error. Anyone please help to resolve this issue.Thanks

Tags: sql, informatica

`iif(Name='Chargedate',TO_CHAR(value,'YYYYMMDD'),null)`

Please help me to change the date format as YYYYMMDD.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

you need to ensure the out/variable column should be a string and value should be a date/time.

```
out_val (string) = iif(Name='Chargedate',TO_CHAR(value,'YYYYMMDD'),null)
```